# Pairwise similarity comparison

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I have a 444-member array of arrays called `final`, with each subarray containing 12 integer members. How can I do a pairwise comparison of the contents of the subarrays to find all pairs with 11 members in common ; failing that, all those with 10 in common ; etc. ?

Is there a built-in similarity measure for numeric arrays?

**EDIT for clarity** : I would be happy if the function returned the pair with maximum similarity, or an array of such pairs in the case of a multi-way tie.

Seeking the function Foo

```
In[1]:= bar = RandomInteger[9, {6, 4}]
Out[1]= {{6, 6, 1, 5}, {4, 0, 9, 3}, {0, 4, 2, 9},
          {4, 6, 0, 6}, {2, 5, 4, 8}, {4, 1, 9, 1}}

In[2]:= Foo[%]
Out[2]= {{4, 0, 9, 3}, {0, 4, 2, 9}}

In[3]:= Foo[bar]
Out[3]= {bar[1], bar[2]}
```

Comment: does order matter? ,e.g {1,2,3}, {2,1,5} "similar" having 2 elements in common. A small test example and desired result would be helpful.

Comment: I have included an example. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: How many **distinct** integers are there in total?

Comment: Oof, I don't know. Approximately 168. They are all primes below 1000, so I'm guessing each prime is present at least once. But I'd like if it was as general as possible.

Comment: How may common items are there in `{{6, 6, 1, 5},  {4, 6, 0, 6}}`? One or two? The accepted answer counts one. Is that correct?

Comment: and please start your reply comment with "@belisarius", otherwise I won't be alerted

Comment: @belisarius: I was making a distinction between what I need and what is as general as possible. My particular case has 12 distinct values in each array, so kguler's code below was precisely what I needed. In the case you cite, I would instinctively say that there are two matched cases, 6 and 6.

Comment: Please note all the details you forgot to include in your question: 1) The numbers are prime, 2) They are all below 1000 3) they are all different.

Comment: @belisarius: thanks, in none of those cases did I think it would affect the resulting code. Even now, I can only see how the third one actually matters. I had to choose between giving too little and too much detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** a single function that combines all the steps:

```
ClearAll[sF, sortedF];
sF = -Length[Intersection @@ #] &;
sortedF = With[{s = Subsets[#, {2}]}, SortBy[s, sF]] &;

First@sortedF@bar
(* {{4, 0, 9, 3}, {0, 4, 2, 9}} *)

sortedpairs = sortedF@bar;
Grid[{#, -sF@#} & /@ sortedpairs]
```

[image]

---

**Original post**

```
sF = -Length[Intersection @@ #] &;
```

Examples:

OP's example:

```
bar= {{6, 6, 1, 5}, {4, 0, 9, 3}, {0, 4, 2, 9}, {4, 6, 0, 6}, {2, 5, 4, 8}, {4, 1, 9, 1}};
SortBy[Subsets[bar, {2}], sF][[1]]
(* {{4, 0, 9, 3}, {0, 4, 2, 9}} *)
```

All pairs sorted by the cardinality of intersection:

```
SeedRandom[123];
arrays = RandomInteger[9, {5, 4}];
pairs = Subsets[arrays, {2}];
srtdpairs = SortBy[pairs, sF];
Grid[Thread[{{"arrays", "pairs", "sorted\npairs"}, Join @@ {{Column@arrays}, 
      Grid[Join[{{"pair", "similarity"}}, {#, -sF@#} & /@ #]] & /@ {pairs, srtdpairs}}}],
 Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**Update:** A `MatrixPlot` of the pairwise similarities for a `50 x 12` array:

```
SeedRandom[12];
ClearAll[sF, sortedF];
sF = -Length[Intersection @@ #] &;
arrays = RandomInteger[9, {50, 12}];
MatrixPlot[Outer[-sF[{##}]/9 &, arrays, arrays, 1], ImageSize -> 500,
           ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: very nice...I posted my ugly answer to with counting repeated elements, hence, the third from the bottom of your update has {6,6} in both. Nonetheless, I continue to learn so much from you +1 :)

Comment: Thank you @ubpdqn. Multiset intersection version is definitely more challenging. I have to say I hope the OP just wants the plain old `Intersection`:)

Comment: This answer fit the bill perfectly, thank you! I'm curious why you put the word 'similarity' in quotes - is there a better term?

Comment: @pgblu, no hidden meaning in quotes :)-- i think 'similarity' is a perfectly fitting term.

Comment: Хорошо. I especially appreciate the middle line that just extracts the top result. With my dataset, the last command results in (as you can imagine) a list of 444 x 443 items!

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

There were some issues with my original post that I have modified.

In case you wish to count {6,6,3},{6,6,2} as having 2 elements in common rather than 1 (as `Intersection` produces), I present this rather ugly code. Note assumes integers from 0 to 9. Could be adapted.

```
func[data_, a_, n_] := 
 Module[{var = Table[Unique["x"], {Length[a]}], r, rl, sub, f, pck, 
   res},
  r = Thread[a -> var];
  rl = Thread[var -> E];
  sub = Subsets[data, {2}];
  f = Times @@ (# /. r) &;
  pck = (Log[#] /. rl) == n & /@ PolynomialGCD @@@ Map[f, sub, {2}];
  res = Normal[GroupBy[Pick[sub, pck], First -> Last]];
  Join @@ Function[{x, y}, {x, #} & /@ y] @@@ res
  ]
```

where `a` is alphabet and `n` is then number of elements that agree. The output is now more like kguler but with counting repeats:

```
Column[# -> 
    Column[Row /@ 
      func[{{6, 6, 1, 5}, {4, 0, 9, 3}, {0, 4, 2, 9}, {4, 6, 0, 
         6}, {2, 5, 4, 8}, {4, 1, 9, 1}}, Range[0, 9], #]] & /@ 
  Range[0, 4], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

More cumbersome example:
r

```
i = {{0, 6, 3, 8}, {8, 8, 8, 0}, {1, 1, 6, 7}, {7, 0, 2, 1}, {5, 1, 
   3, 5}, {5, 9, 7, 9}, {2, 9, 8, 9}, {5, 4, 5, 2}, {5, 8, 5, 8}, {6, 
   4, 0, 6}, {6, 3, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 5, 2}, {2, 3, 1, 
   0}, {2, 2, 7, 7}, {6, 1, 2, 1}, {0, 9, 3, 6}, {2, 9, 2, 3}, {0, 8, 
   2, 7}, {3, 7, 8, 0}}
FlipView[Framed /@ (# -> 
      Row[{Column[Row /@ func[ri, Range[0, 9], #]], 
        Length@(func[ri, Range[0, 9], #])}] & /@ Range[0, 4])]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) this may well be what the OP wants. Btw, counted (manually) 16 system functions  in your `Module` (not including `Rule`, `Map`, `Apply`...):)

Comment: @kguler... I said it was ugly...just had a flight of fancy converting to polynomial then using Log and replacement of variable e to count...it's been a long week so almost certainly this was poor but perversely fun

Comment: ubdqn, i really meant it as a compliment:)

Comment: Compliments from me too - I look forward to exploring your solution further! My green check mark went to kguler's answer only because my sets don't in fact contain any duplicates. Your solution looks like it would be even more general though, is that right?